# Is there a more "Swift"-esque pattern for creating an NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: core-data, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In the standard Core Data template for iOS projects, the creation of an `NSFetchedResultsController` seems very much like Objective-C was shoe-horned into Swift.

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
         //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
         abort()
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}    
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil
```

As someone still very new to Swift, how would I go about translating this into something closer to Swift's style? Lazy variables? Initializing it with a closure? Something else?

Comment: I don't know, that's pretty Swiftesque - `fetchedResultsController` is a computed property that initializes and returns the unwrapped value of an Optional stored property... But the lazy stored properties initialized with an immediately-called anonymous closure in `AppDelegate` do seem cleaner. (Whew, did I get all the Swiftisms?)